# Question about the RTAI and version Of kernel

Tags: 12.04, kernel, realtime

I have a `ubuntu 3.8.0-29` geniric and the `gcc 4.6.3 .` 
I will to install the `RTAI` , what is the version of kernel and the version of kernel to download ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as building is concerned, it looks like all you may need:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic autoconf automake aclocal libtool
```

Extract the tar.bz2 file and take a look at the README.INSTALL file for complete instructions.

According to the documentation, it just talks about 3.x and doesn't specify a specific kernel version as far as I can tell.

Try building and compiling on your current kernel version and if you get stuck with an error, post that error and we can go from there.

---

With that said, there is no realtime kernel for Ubuntu as it is depreciated. We now use the lowlatency kernel instead.

You can install the lowlatency kernel for version 3.2 by running the following command (you will need to have the universe repository enabled):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-image-lowlatency
```

Ubuntustudio uses the lowlatency kernel by default and I believe also employs other default settings to enhance this. Also, I think this is mostly for audio recording but I'm not sure. [Click here for more info.](http://ubuntustudio.org/)